# equation involving a singular symmetric matrix

Tags: matrices

how can I prove the following identity:

[image]

note that the 3*3 matrix on the left side is singular.
maybe I can somehow insert the 1*3 and 3*1 vectors inside the inverse operation?

thanks!

Comment: Please explain what is the inverse of a singular matrix! Without it I cannot interpret your equation.

Answer (score 0):

If the matrix is singular, the inverse operation is not defined. I'm confused as how to go about looking at the matrix on the left. Perhaps a little more information on the origin of the problem is needed.

Now this statement is obviously true if the inverse signs are not included. Both statements evaluate to $a_{11}+a_{22}−2 a_{12}$.

Also this is true if the left matrix is $\left(\begin{array}{ccc} a_{11} & a_{12} & 0 \\ a_{12} & a_{22} & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ \end{array} \right)^{-1}$

In fact this works if the left matrix is $\left(\begin{array}{ccc} a_{11} & a_{12} & x \left(a_{11}+a_{12}\right) \\ a_{12} & a_{22} & x \left(a_{12}+a_{22}\right) \\ x \left(a_{11}+a_{12}\right) & x \left(a_{12}+a_{22}\right) & z \\\end{array}\right)^{-1}$ for any $x, z$. Note $z$ should be a constant and independent of $a_{11}, a_{12}, a_{22}$. $x$ should also be a constant.

Comment: here is the origin of the problem: I have developed a Fisher Information Matrix for a vector of 3 parameters, and I get this singular matrix. I need to get the Cramer Rao Lower Bound for a tranformation of this vector of parmeters. that is why I multyply the inverse of the matrix by row and column vectors from both sides.